# Correct postfix smtp restrictions order of processing

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I have this smtp restriction in postfix configuration file:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

to my knowledge, if `permit_sasl_authenticated` says that specific user is authenticated, then rest of restrictions are not checked?

What if I want to make sure that `permit_sasl_authenticated` and `check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031`, if they both say yes, Only then the email should be passed otherwise no?

Actually I am trying to setup cluebringer, but getting problem that it is saying `Sender address rejected`, even after the sender is authenticated properly from SASL.

Here is my `postconf -n` output:

```
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = 91.91.98.67, localhost
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mauth.fdomain.co.uk, localhost
myhostname = mauth.fdomain.co.uk
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/relaydomains.cf
relayhost =
smtp_bind_address = 91.91.9.7
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/authsmtp.conf
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname Freezone Internet ESMTP
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
smtpd_data_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/freezonewc.ca
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/freezonewc.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/freezonewc.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/transport.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be honest, your restrictions are a bit of a mess right now. The postfix-users mailing list usually recommends to gather all restrictions under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` or `smtpd_relay_restrictions` (Postfix 2.10 only). The reason for this is that it enhances readability and doesn't really make much of a difference with `smtpd_delay_reject=yes`.

Furthermore, a policy service should rarely reply with an accept/ok statement but rather with DUNNO. So in your case, first asking the policy service, giving it a chance to say REJECT and then checking SASL seems like a better way, unless your policy service does return OK in some cases.

Without knowing neither the exact nature of your policy service nor your requirements, I'd start out with something like this:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions =
  # subject even authenticated users and trusted networks
  # to the policy check
  check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
  permit_mynetworks
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  defer_unauth_destination

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  # we exclude our networks and SASL authenticated users
  # from all further checks.
  # since I don't know if the policy service is relevant
  # for unauthenticated mail, I commented it out here
  # check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
  warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname
  warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender
  reject_invalid_hostname
  reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
```

See the comments in my configuration snippet for some caveats.

Answer (score 1):

> to my knowledge, if permit_sasl_authenticated says that specific user is authenticated, then rest of restrictions are not checked.?

you are right, but only in the current smtpd_xxx_restrictions

Just remove permit_sasl_authenticated from smtpd_sender_restrictions and move all verifications to the policy service

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, ...
```

There would be available the following options

```
sasl_method
sasl_username
sasl_sender
```

These attributes would be empty in case of no SASL authentication. On the logical level it could be something like the following

```
if [ policy_service_return_code == OK && sasl_username not empty ]
   return OK
else
   return REJECT
```

Comment: didnt get you..

Comment: what kind of policy service are you using?

Comment: Cluebringer policyd

Comment: Which one, v1 or v2?

Comment: its version v2..